# Text from TextView does not adapt

Tags: android, layout, textview

Hi guys I've made a TextView and I try to adapt the text for every screens with:

```
            double TextSize =(dm.WidthPixels / dm.ScaledDensity)/ 24;
            TextView.SetTextSize (ComplexUnitType.Dip,(int)TextSize);
```

This is for LDPI screens and it work on all device where I tested my app except one where the text appear enough big.Any idea why it happens?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Very confusing with uppercase variables!

Comment: There was a bug in Android that somehow screwed up decreasing a TextView's text size. I'll see if I can find it.

Comment: Might this be the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10908150/how-to-decrease-textview-text-size-in-android-4-0?

Comment: @FD_ Actually yes.So it can't be fixed?

Comment: `This is for LDPI screens` ... you should always reason with **mdpi**, since that is where **1dp = 1px**. Relate your calculations to a standard 3.2" 320x480 **mdpi** screen, and you'll always be fine.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein You mean use same calculation for all kind of screens? (LDPI,MDPI,HDPI and XHDPI)?

Comment: @FrankN.Stein But not all device have same dpi resolution... Can you make me understand?

Comment: obviously. **mdpi** has a `standardized` resolution of 160 dpi. This is the **normal** resolution (1dp = 1px). ldpi has a standardized resolution of 120 dpi (0.75 * 160). hdpi has a standardized resolution of 240 dpi (1.5 * 160). And so on.

Answer (score 0):

If [Android issue 22493](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=22493) is your problem, there is a simple workaround. Simply run this code after setting the TextView's size:

```
 tv.append("\uFEFF");  // zero width space
```

This will append a zero-width space to the TextView's text (no visual changes) and will fix the height.